# Pro Tools Auto Conform

Tags: edl

Hi all. Is there anyway I can conform dialogue from poly BWFs into Pro Tools using EDL? Auto conform was a wonderful procedure. I am not sure why non of the popular digital editors do it. There must be a better way than mod-matching cues?! many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of third party applications that can do this sort of thing. Please read the [post on my blog](http://www.osd-uk.com/2011/11/the-question-of-conforming-what-software-to-use/) all about the options.

Also with the improved field recorder support in Pro Tools 10 it is possible to undertake an assembly from within Pro tools. See my [Pro tools 10 for post FAQ](http://www.osd-uk.com/2011/10/pro-tools-10-post-related-faq/)

Hope that helps,

Mike.

Answer (score 1):

EdiLoad can load an audio EDL and create 'conform reference tracks' that you open in Pro Tools to conform poly WAVs

http://www.soundsinsync.com/products/ediload

Answer (score 0):

Mike hit the nail on the head. If you're using the conform functions in PT be sure to check out the Field Recorder Workflow document under Help. I'm using the Conform functions on a show now with good results. AVID also has this video tutorial:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gz9e9LuIdXU

Answer (score 0):

Everyone I know who does this in the machine room uses VirtualKaty.  They have a free full 48 hour trial version available on their website. http://www.virtualkaty.com/